# Create bar chart using mysql data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I want create bar using mysql data which is returned in JSON Format.

```
[
  {
    "Score": "84",
    "Trainer": "Jamshaid",
    "Subject Name": "Java"
  },
  {
    "Score": "50",
    "Trainer": "Zaid",
    "Subject Name": "Android"
  },
  {
    "Score": "40",
    "Trainer": "Sajjad",
    "Subject Name": "iOS"
  },
  {
    "Score": "50",
    "Trainer": "Jamshaid",
    "Subject Name": "iOS"
  }
]
```

I want to create like [this](http://blueflame-software.com/demo/bar-chart-with-data-from-mysql-using-highcharts/) chart

But problem is that this gets formatted from Table. But I have data in JSON as shown above.

Here is the link I am following. Can we convert the JSON Data in a Format so that it can populate chart based on the Data as shown

https://blueflame-software.com/bar-chart-with-data-from-mysql-using-highcharts/

Comment: @AliMamdov I have checked above format is fine JSON format.

Comment: I corrected the format, there was a missing { in the last JSON object.
What do you want to plot against what? Like what is in the X Axis and Y Axis

Comment: @MohammadSanaulla In Y Axis we will shown Subject Name on X-Axis Score Like shown in above graph

Comment: Have a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68smjpeL/ tried something let me know if it meets the requirement. We dont have the scores for people in all the subjects

Comment: @MohammadSanulla This is fine. But the JSON is dynamic from server so how we will populate data filed in Graph we will have 3 Names that is fine but how we will get data for these three from JSON

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla main problem is getting dynamic data from JSON in graph

Comment: It is possible to parse the current JSON format in Javascript and build the data for the chart I will provide  that in sometime.
But I would recommend you to alter the way you are getting the JSON from server and group it against each language something like : {"Java": [], "iOS":[], "Andriod":[]}

Comment: grouping from server is not easy that is why we were parsing json in javascript

Comment: You can try this http://jsfiddle.net/68smjpeL/100/ I have declared the JSON response as a variable and did procession in the Javascript
And if it suits your requirement, I can post that as an answer and you can accept it :)

Comment: @MohammadSanaulla Thanks you can post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process the JSON in the Javascript to build the data required for the chart as shown below:

```
var jsonFromServer = [
  {
    "Score": "84",
    "Trainer": "Jamshaid",
    "Subject Name": "Java"
  },
  {
    "Score": "50",
    "Trainer": "Zaid",
    "Subject Name": "Android"
  },
  {
    "Score": "40",
    "Trainer": "Sajjad",
    "Subject Name": "iOS"
  },
  {
    "Score": "50",
    "Trainer": "Jamshaid",
    "Subject Name": "iOS"
  }
];
```

The above is data from server captured in a variable

The below code helps you to extract the Y axis Values (i.e the unique subject names) from the JSON response:

```
function getSubjects(){
    var subjectsMap = {};
  $.each(jsonFromServer, function(index, value){
    if(!subjectsMap[value['Subject Name']]){
        subjectsMap[value['Subject Name']] = 1;
    }
  });
  return $.map(subjectsMap, function(index, val){ return val; });
}
```

Then we need to extract the Scores for each trainer in different subject which should be of form: [{name: "Trainer", data: []}] where data is an array of scores in subject whose order should be same as the order of subjects appearing in the Y axis data. Which can be achieved using the below code:

```
function getTrainers(){
    var trainersMap = {};
  $.each(jsonFromServer, function(index, value){
    if(!trainersMap[value['Trainer']]){
        trainersMap[value['Trainer']] = 1;
    }
  });
  return $.map(trainersMap, function(index, val){ return val; });
}
function getMarks(){
  var subjects = getSubjects();
  var trainers= getTrainers();
  var marks = {};
  //initialize the trainers scores in all subjects to 0
   $.each(trainers, function(index, trainer){
    if ( !marks[trainer]){
        marks[trainer] = {};
    }
    $.each(subjects, function(idx2, sub){
        marks[trainer][sub] = 0;
    });
  });

  //now populate with the actual values obtained from server
  $.each(subjects, function(idx2, sub){
    $.each(jsonFromServer, function(index, value){
        var trainer = value['Trainer'];
        var subName = value['Subject Name'];
      var score = value['Score'];
      if ( sub == subName){
            marks[trainer][sub] = score;  
      }
    });

  });

  //now format the marks object into the format required for highcharts
  //i.e an array of object with properties [{name: "", data:[]}]
  return $.map(marks, function(val, index){ 
    var scoreArray = [];
    $.each(val, function(index, score){
        scoreArray.push(parseInt(score));
    });
    return {"name": index, "data": scoreArray}; 
  });

}
```

The working code can be found in the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/68smjpeL/100/).